# .NET Console read and write problem

Tags: c#

Code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write(20);
        int myAge = Console.Read() + 10;
        Console.WriteLine(myAge);
    }
}
```

After printing 20 it hangs out and nothing is printed :(

Comment: Are you typing something on the console? `The Read method blocks its return while you type input characters; it terminates when you press the Enter key.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx

Comment: What's up with the formatting? The code block doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Console.Write(20);
    int myAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) + 10;
    Console.WriteLine(myAge);
```

The code waits for you to input something.

Comment: why the downvote? If you'd have `Console.Read() + 10`, the `int` representation of the `char` read would be calculated + 10 and put into myAge. Surely not what is to be achieved.

Comment: I thought it takes it from Console.WriteLine() so I don't need it anymore!
It's an output so there's no sense right?
However if I don't use Parse and only Console.Read(), although it returns integer it gives me wrong value not the one entered why so?

Answer (score 4):

[Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) is waiting for you to input something, that is why it stops after it prints out `20`.  Try typing something and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You should use [ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) instead.

```
    Console.Write(20);

    string line = Console.ReadLine();

    int number, myAge = 0;

    if (int.TryParse(line, out number))
        myAge = number + 10;


    Console.WriteLine(myAge);
```

Comment: I thought it takes it from Console.WriteLine() so I don't need it anymore! It's an output so there's no sense right? However if I don't use Parse and only Console.Read(), although it returns integer it gives me wrong value not the one entered why so?

Comment: Have a look at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx